# How VBA counts number of Rows?

Tags: excel, vba

`NumOfRows = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row`

I want to know that how exactly this command count the number of rows?
I want to understand the line by line code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translation could be as follows:

in `Activesheet` goto `cell A1` next move down by `number of all rows in sheet minus 1` but `keep the same column (0)` next `move up to first not empty cell in column 0` (assuming that last cell was empty) and get the row of the cell where you have been moved.

As a result this code is not returning number of ROWS but number of SINGLE ROW where you have been moved. But it seems to be the same as number of rows of data table if such table starts in Cell A1 and is continuous down direction.

BTW, more popular version of your code is this one:

```
NumOfRows = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

where you get the same result.